# dart.io examples from dartlang threw 'uncaught' error on dartpad (beginner level)

Tags: dart

Im trying to follow tutorials from "Dart for Absolute Beginner" book and from dartlang https://www.dartlang.org/tutorials/dart-vm/cmdline "stdin" examples to accept keyboard input however dartpad will show 'uncaught' for every examples i tried.

Sample code:

```
import 'dart.io'
void main() {
  stdout.writeln('Type something');
  String input = stdin.readLineSync();
  stdout.writeln('You typed: $input');
}
```

Can somebody point me to what I should add ? A try and catch block ? How do I do that or get to that ? I am only on page 41 for the "Dart for Absolutely Beginner" book so don;t expect me to know much.

Comment: When I run your code in DartPad I get `Error compiling to JavaScript:
Imports other than dart: are not supported on Dartpad`

Comment: You are also missing a semicolon on your first line. Not sure if that matters.

Comment: Yeahh .. I miss that semicolon on the first import line, but it will not work even with it.

Comment: You can try it online at jdoodle where `dart:io` is supported:
https://www.jdoodle.com/execute-dart-online/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[DartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org) transpiles Dart to JavaScript before it can execute the code.

`dart:io` is limited to console applications.

`dart:html` provides abstraction of the API available in the browser, but there is no equivalent to `stdin` or `readLine` in the browser.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, that could be the reason (I have to check). However, dartpad also have a console output. It didn't work there ?

Comment: The console in the browser is mostly for debugging purposes. I don't think there is a way to read from it. It is possible to print to the browser console using `print('foo');`

Comment: Thank you, I really feel that is the problem. I will try on vscode and see for myself. Will update this thread once I am satisfied. Thank you so much for your input.

Comment: I'm still wondering about the error message you got. Did you see my comment directly below your question?

Comment: I don't have the same error as yours. My dartpad just shows 'uncaught' in red. The command works as it supposed to in the terminal. I shouldn't have used the dartpad for command line apps.

Comment: That's really weird. "uncaught" indicates the code run, but even the invalid syntax of `import 'dart.io'` which should have a `:` instead of `.` should lead to a different error.

Answer (score 0):

you can use that website it's support dart:io
https://replit.com/languages/dart